# Issues in example custom field inheriting foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models

in model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    editor =  ProfiledUserField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.author_name)
```

---

custom ProfiledUserField

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey
from django.forms.fields import Select, TextInput
import datetime

class ProfiledUser(object):
    def __init__(self,user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user

    def create_user(self,username,password="user123"):
        user = User.objects.create(username=username,password=password)
        return user


class ProfiledUserField(ForeignKey):
    description = "a custom user field"
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super(ProfiledUserField,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    def to_python(self,value):
        return value


    def get_prep_value(self,value):
        print 'in get prep value',datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%f")
        return value.id

    def get_db_prep_value(self,value,connection,prepared=False):
        print 'in get Db prep value',datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%f")
        return value.id
```

there's nothing in admin section except registering the model.

when i try to save an object via admin, the to_python is called twice ,first with User object selected from select widget,  second time with a value None, thus thugh i had selected/provided input to widget, its not there second time to_python is called resulting in validation error "field cant be left blank" (as editor cant be null or blank by default)

when i try to save it via python shell,

```
>>> author= Author.objects.create(author_name="Khalil Gibran" , email="kh@gmail.com", editor=user)
AttributeError: 'Author' object has no attribute 'editor_id'

>>> Author
<class 'articles.models.Author'>
>>> Author.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__module__': 'articles.models', 'MultipleObjectsReturned': <class 'articles.models.MultipleObjectsReturned'>, '_meta': <Options for Author>, '__str__': <function __str__ at 0x97d0d4c>, 'article_set': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor object at 0x97e0b0c>, '_base_manager': <django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x97e02ec>, 'objects': <django.db.models.manager.ManagerDescriptor object at 0x97e034c>, 'editor': <django.db.models.fields.subclassing.Creator object at 0x97e024c>, 'DoesNotExist': <class 'articles.models.DoesNotExist'>, '__doc__': 'Author(id, author_name, email, editor_id)', '_default_manager': <django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x97e02ec>})
>>> dir(Author)
['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_base_manager', '_default_manager', '_deferred', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_set_pk_val', 'article_set', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'editor', 'full_clean', 'objects', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'save', 'save_base', 'serializable_value', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']
```

ysql shell:

```
mysql> describe articles_author;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author_name | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| editor_id   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

what am i doing wrong?

if i had in models null=True, blank=True, same code works perfectly fine but otherwise i cant save it.
again if i remove the **metaclass** =Subfieldbase, everything works fine.
what is the explanation ?

Comment: Your `Author` class does not have `editor_id` mentioned. But it is there in the table. Did you change the model at any point of time? If you have synced once and then removed the field it gets ugly unless you are using migrations.

Comment: Another point to be noted is that `objects.create` immediately creates the object. So any field that is not nullable is expected to be added before the object is created.

Comment: `ForeignKey.get_attname` appends that `_id` to the field name.

Comment: When creating an user use `User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)`. Otherwise you have to use `user_obj.set_password(raw_password)`